# How to avoid splitting on a delimiter if it appears inside quotes?

Tags: python

I have problem in splitting data. I have data as follows in CSV file:

```
"a";"b";"c;d";"e"
```

The problem is when I used `line.split(";")` function, it splits even between `c` and `d`. I don't want `c` and `d` to be separated.  Later I need to store these four values in four different columns in a table, but using this function I get five different columns.

I want the results to be `"a" "b" "cd" "e"`.

I tried with `line.split('";"')`, but it did not help.

Comment: Use the `csv` module to parse CSV file.

Comment: Why should the `;` between `c` an `d` be dropped?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("yourfile.csv", "rb"), delimiter=';')
for row in reader:
    print row
```

Try this out.

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("yourfile.csv", "rb"), delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE )
for row in reader:
    print row
```

This ^^^ if you want quotes preserved

**Edit:** If you want `';'` removed from the field content (`'c;d'` = `'cd'` case) - you may do the post processing on rows returned, something like this:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("yourfile.csv", "rb"), delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE )
for row in reader:
    print [item.replace(';', '') for item in row]
```

Answer (score 0):

In other contexts, the shlex.split() function could be used

Comment: How can it split on a different delimiter than whitespace?